# CSS multiple :not doesn't work as expected

Tags: css

I have the follow code:

```css
a {
    color: black
}

a:not(.test1) {
    color: red
}

a:not(.test1):not(.test2) {
    color: green;
}

a.test {
    color: blue
}
```

```html
<a class='test'>
    TEST
</a>
```

Why the result is green? I expected the result color will be blue

Comment: It's just that the selectors `a:not(.test1):not(.test2)` are more *specific* than just `a.test`. If you inspect the element and view the declared styles you will notice that both styles are applicable but the rule with more *specificity* wins.

Comment: And why if I replace "a:not(.test1):not(.test2)" by "a:not(.test1, .test2)" the result is blue?

Comment: `a:not(.test1, .test2)` is not valid syntax structure, refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Syntax

Comment: The selector list syntax will *probably* become valid in the future:  https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectors `a:not(.test1):not(.test2)` are more specific than just `a.test`.

If you inspect the element and view the declared styles you will notice that both styles are applicable but the rule with more specificity wins.

You can resolve this issue declaring another *pseudo-class* to account for `a.test` as well, e.g:

```
a:not(.test):not(.test1):not(.test2) {
    color: green;
}
```

However, consider avoiding *over-qualifying* style rules by declaring them too specifically whenever possible.

[:not() - CSS | MDN (Syntax reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Syntax)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
a {
    color: black
}

a:not(.test1) {
    color: red
}

a:not(.test):not(.test1):not(.test2) {
    color: green;
}

a.test {
    color: blue
}
```

```html
<a class='test'>
    TEST
</a>
<br>
<a class='test1'>
    TEST 1
</a>
<br>
<a class='test2'>
    TEST 2
</a>
<br>
<a>
    TEST (no class)
</a>
```